# static media is not visible in django photologue

Tags: django, python-3.x

**In settings.py**

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static/')
STATIC_URL = "/static/"

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
```

**I have following urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)), 
    url(r'^photologue/', include('photologue.urls', namespace='photologue')),
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True }),
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT, }),
]
```

---

**I get following error:**

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/media/photologue/photos/jagadamba.png
Raised by:  django.views.static.serve
"D:\Projects\testproject\bon_photo_app\nostos_bcon\static/photologue/photos/jagadamba.png" does not exist
```

I can see the file in that path. Is that because django is getting wrong / and \ . I can see that media is missing in the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.**STATIC_ROOT**, 'show_indexes': True })
```

I think there Should be MEDIA_ROOT mine in settings.py is like `'/home/x/Work/Project/app/static/images/'`

```
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
```

Comment: Great That was the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try do next one:

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
INSTALLED_APPS += (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)
STATIC_ROOT = "/static/"
MEDIA_ROOT = "/media/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    "/srv/glue/www/static",
)
```

Add to urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('django.contrib.staticfiles.views',
                            url(r'^/(?P<path>.*)$', 'serve'),
                            )
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Comment: What is the logic behind this code? I am still not able to resolve.